# "Early"---- adjective to adverb

Tags: adverbs

> In his **early** matches he was not quite good.

But if I would like to say the same:

> When he was playing { gap }  he wasn't quite good.

Should I put **early** as an adverb in the gap?

Comment: When he was playing *earlier* he wasn't quite good?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if the adverb *early* works after the verb in this sentence. I would say

> When he was *first* playing, he wasn’t very good.

Or maybe more idiomatically,

> When he *first started* playing, he wasn’t very good.

I’ve also replaced “not quite good” with “not very good”. The latter is a common euphemism meaning “actually quite bad”.

Comment: *Early* does work as an adverb in that position, but it would give the sentence a different meaning: when he was playing early [in the morning] (or earlier than he usually played), he wasn't good.

Comment: @Juhasz definitely.  Using early in the second sentence would change the context to earlier in the day, versus in the first sentence which seems to indicate that at the beginning of his career he wasn't very good.  We lack context from the OP to know which one he actually means.

Comment: "In his early matches" could mean at the start of a tournament or other event, or it could mean early in his career. "His early play wasn't very good" has the same ambiguity.